# End all macro on keypress

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to add a line to my code that will end it when for example, the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key is pressed.

I've managed to get the others to work, and some sites out there say that the following/similar would work, though I find the opposite to be true.

```
Sub CellMover()

    Application.OnKey "{ESC}", End

    Application.OnKey "{UP}", "MoveUp"

    Application.OnKey "{DOWN}", "MoveDown"

    Application.OnKey "{LEFT}", "MoveLeft"

    Application.OnKey "{RIGHT}", "MoveRight"

End Sub
```

My hopes would be that when I press <kbd>ESC</kbd>, the next time(s) I press any of the arrow keys, it doesn't then also run the associated macros.

Comment: Doesn't `ESC` normally halt execution of a macro anyway (provided Events are enabled to run) ?

Comment: @CLR I believe that is does usually, but for some reason it's not happening for me now

Comment: Hmm this really is interesting, it's as if `Application.OnKey` was bound outside of the procedure call

Comment: Have you got some kind of loop running? Make sure there's a `DoEvents` in it to check for events such as `OnKey`.

Comment: @CLR I don't have any loops running in this code, but I'll have a go with DoEvents and see what I can come up with

Answer (score 0):

Using the [`Stop`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/stop-statement) statement does seem to do the trick *(essentially creates a break-point)*

```
Public Sub halt()
   Stop 'prevents all further execution
End Sub
```

So your code would look like this:

```
Sub CellMover()
    Application.OnKey "{ESC}", "halt"
    Application.OnKey "{UP}", "MoveUp"
    Application.OnKey "{DOWN}", "MoveDown"
    Application.OnKey "{LEFT}", "MoveLeft"
    Application.OnKey "{RIGHT}", "MoveRight"
End Sub
```

Comment: As a note, I did spend good hour on this, fiddling around with global variables, interrupts, ends and so on. Issue is, you need to prevent code from running during the Run-Time not after the Run-Time which is nigh on impossible. Given `End` and `Exit` do simply end the Run-Time and the procedure begins anew. *(even that took me a good while to figure out)*, as I was foolishly trying to pass values around

Comment: That's almost perfect, but that completely disables my arrow keys. Is there any way the macro can be stopped in such a way that I can use them, or would I be going about the entire project the wrong way? If it's impossible don't worry about it I can try another way :)

Comment: @CLR Not that I know of. I kind of wonder who downvoted tho and why :(

Comment: I have no idea. I literally can't change it because I'm still x<15 Reputation